# Error on Loop Through Outlook MailItems using Late Binding in Access VBA: User-defined Type Not Defined

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to filter Outlook's Deleted Items folder then loop through all the items that fit the criteria.

I'm using late binding. There's a problem with the way I'm declaring.

Here are my variables

```
Public OutlApp  As Object
Public OutlNameSpace As Object
Public OutlMail  As Object
Public OutlAttach As Object
Public OutlFolder   As Object
Public OutlItem   As Object
Public OutlMailItem As Object

Public OutlSenderLogin    As String
Public OutlSenderName   As String
Public OutlSenderEMail  As String
Public OutlDateReceived   As String
Public OutlDateSent  As String
Public OutlSubject  As String
Public OutlMsgBody     As String

Public OutlSubjectCriteria1      As String
Public OutlSubjectCriteria2      As String
Public OutlSubjectCriteria3      As String
Public OutlSubjectCriteria4      As String
Public OutlFilter   As String
Public OutlStartDate  As String
Public OutlEndDate      As String
Public OutlSentBy    As String
Public OutlSentBy2    As String
Public OutlSentBy3    As String
```

I get an error at "If **TypeOf OutlFolder.Items(i) Is MailItem** Then", the bolded part is highlighted.

The error is "User-defined Type Not Defined".

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const OutlFolderInbox As Integer = 6
Const OutlFolderIDeletedItems As Integer = 3
Public Function OutlookDeletedItems()

CurPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"

Dim i, CountOfItems As Long
Dim EmailContTD, EmailContNew As String
       
Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set OutlNameSpace = OutlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OutlFolder = OutlNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OutlFolderIDeletedItems)
Set OutlMail = GetObject(, "Outlook.MailItem")

OutlMyUTC = 7 

OutlStartDate = Format(DateAdd("h", -OutlMyUTC, Date), "\'m/d/yyyy\") & " 12:00 AM'"
OutlSentBy = "hhh, fff" '
OutlSentBy2 = "fffff@service-now.com" '/
OutlSubjectCriteria1 = "blah *"
OutlSubjectCriteria2 = "blah"
OutlSubjectCriteria3 = "blah"

OutlFilter = "@SQL= ((urn:schemas:httpmail:sendername = '" & OutlSentBy & "' OR urn:schemas:httpmail:sendername = '" & OutlSentBy2 & "') And urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived >= " & OutlStartDate & _
                            ") AND (urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = '" & OutlSubjectCriteria3 & "' OR urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = '" & OutlSubjectCriteria2 & "' OR urn:schemas:httpmail:subject Like '" & OutlSubjectCriteria1 & "') "
                            
CountOfItems = OutlFolder.Items.Restrict(OutlFilter).Count
If CountOfItems = 0 Then
    Exit Function
End If

Set OutlMailItem = OutlFolder.Items.Restrict(OutlFilter)

With OutlItem
    For i = CountOfItems To 1 Step -1 
        If TypeOf OutlFolder.Items(i) Is MailItem Then
            Set OutlMailItem = OutlFolder.Items(i)

            OutlDateReceived = OutlMailItem.ReceivedTime
            OutlSubject = OutlMailItem.Subject
            OutlMsgBody = OutlMailItem.Body

            If OutlSubject Like OutlSubjectCriteria1 Then
                EmailContTD = Replace(OutlMsgBody, Chr(34), "")       
            End If

            If OutlSubject = OutlSubjectCriteria2 Then
                EmailContNew = Replace(OutlMsgBody, Chr(34), "")
                DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO SNNew ( Contents ) SELECT """ & EmailContNew & """ AS Expr1 FROM DUAL;"              
            End If

            If OutlSubject = OutlSubjectCriteria3 Then
                For Each OutlAttach In OutlItem.Attachments
                    OutlAttach.SaveAsFile CurPath & "_Load\MyTickets.xlsx"                            
                Next OutlAttach
            End If
        End If
        
        EmailContTD = ""
        EmailContNew = ""
    Next
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Why is this in code `01:36 PM' */`?

Comment: mistake, my version doesn't have it. i edited before posting, removed comments, etc. and messed up. will edit now

Comment: Are these Public declarations in the same module as the function? OutlFolderInbox is declared as a Public and a Const - I get conflict error. Have you run Debug>Compile?

Comment: they're in a different one but i've been doing it this way for ages for a ton of functions and never a problem. OutFOlderInbox is declared twice by accident, but mine is in a different module so it just uses the one from this module. updating original

Comment: Need to declare ALL variables - CurPath and OutlMyUTC are not. I fixed those and odd, I am not getting compile error on the offending line in your question.

Comment: do you have the outlook reference enabled? i do not. and i have them all declared, sorry, didn't want to post my huge variable list

Comment: Yes, I have the reference. Got code to run. No error on that line which surprises me. I had to comment `'Set OutlMail = GetObject(, "Outlook.MailItem")`.

Comment: i don't have the reference though, take yours off and you will get the error. that's why i'm late binding, so that when i give this db to other people with different versions, they don't get errors because of references :( if i can use references, i'd be good, i had code that worked

Comment: If you're explicitly late binding (`As Object`/`As Variant`, and no library reference to define the types, their members) then the types defined in that library aren't known to the compiler - so `MailItem` in the `TypeOf...Is` expression isn't defined at compile-time; you can't do that kind of type-checking without a reference to the library. The `TypeName` function should work though: `If TypeName(OutlFolder.Items(i)) = "MailItem" Then`. Make sure `Option Explicit` is specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> If TypeOf OutlFolder.Items(i) Is MailItem Then
> ```

The `MailItem` class isn't defined, the compiler isn't lying - you would need to reference the Outlook library (or otherwise define a `MailItem` class) for that code to compile.

You can use the `TypeName` function for late-bound type checks (note, it's less robust than the compile-time check):

```
If TypeName(OutlFolder.Items(i)) = "MailItem" Then
```

Make sure `Option Explicit` is at the top of every module, too: late binding (explicit or not) already makes a lot of typos blow things up at run-time (error 438; prefer early binding whenever possible, the compiler is then able to pick up problems much earlier). With this option on typos won't become on-the-fly `Variant` values that can produce weird unexpected bugs.

Comment: I also prefer early binding and have been using it for years but now I need to start sharing my dbs and I run into problems with different versions of access and errors. I couldn't find a solution other than to late bind. As for Option Explicit, I always have it, at least it weeds out some errors before run time

Comment: @lalachka I've always worked in environments where all users had the same version; I can see how early binding can cause problems when that isn't the case (you'd need to develop the solution with the lowest supported version). You can use `#If LATEBIND Then` conditionally-compiled statements/blocks, and use `#Const` to define module-scope precompiler constants (you'll want these to be just switches that are either 0 or 1). You can also define project-scope precompiler constants in the *Project Properties* dialog.

Comment: For larger/involved projects and/or depending on how much abstraction makes sense, it could be worth wrapping the functionality of the library that you need, and then using early-bound calls against that wrapper object (which makes the late-bound calls against the wrapped library objects).

Comment: Yeah, I know the earliest version is a possibility... doesn't appeal to me. Your other solution, how is it preferable to late binding? Meaning, what am I gaining by doing it this way?

Comment: Lol your second part is way above my level. Probably the first as well :)

Comment: @lalachka it's *an option* - conditional compilation isn't *preferable* IMO, but it makes it possible to write the code early-bound and benefit from as much compile-time checks as possible, and then toggle a precompiler constant, remove all library references, and distribute a solution that's all late-bound, and works. As for the wrapper, it's just a matter of abstraction: a procedure is an abstraction over a bunch of lower-level things, themselves abstracting other lower-level things, and so on until it's all straight-up ones and zeroes - a class merely serves to abstract things.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. Hmm, thats an interesting idea, I might use it. So, basically, I'm writing 2 versions, one is late bound and one is early bound?

Comment: Its 6am where I am, so I'm going to check out, but I read the first few pages, you're very good at explaining, I will finish it over the weekend. Thank you!!